# How can transform non homogeneous boundary conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

How can I transform the non homogeneous boundary conditions to homogeneous boundary conditions in the the following ordinary differential equation?
$$
\begin{cases}
y’’’’’(x)= e^{-x} \cdot y^2(x) \\
y(0)=1, \; y(1)=e, \\
y’(0)=1, \;y’(1)=e, \\
y''(0)=1, \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Write $y=u+v$, where $v$ is an arbitrary function satisfying the given boundary conditions. One possibility is $v(x)=e^x$, which leads to the modified ODE
$$
u'''''+e^x=e^{-x}(u+e^x)^2,
$$
or
$$
u'''''=e^{-x}u^2+2u,
$$
with boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=u'(0)=u'(1)=u''(0)=0$.